# styling tabs using styles.xml

Tags: android

I have a row of 5 tabs at the bottom of my app.  The problem is the text is cut off on some of them. I want to be able to have the text in each tab stack on top of each other instead of following along horizontally aswell as move the text into the center of the tab instead of sitting at the bottom.

I have created a styles.xml file and have altered the text size but I am not sure how to add the requirments I stated above to it.  Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style resources uses the same XML attributes as an XML file. You altered the text size successfully, so just add the attributes for the other desired styles. If you don't know which attributes to use, just go to your XML file and type `android:` and your IDE should pop up a list of all Android XML attributes. If not, go to the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) page and read up on the "XML Attributes" section.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked through that but can't find an attribute for any of the tasks I'm trying to achive. Do you know what ones?

Comment: I haven't programmed via Android in a long time. My best advice is to do some trial-and-error. That's how I learned :P Your question is a little vague, but I think you need to restrict the width via `android:layout_width` to have the text "stack on top of each other." (this is what I mean by "vague") `android:gravity="center"` allows you to specify the gravity of your tabs children.